# Why are the images in WidgetTab not shown if minSdkVersion>10?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-tabhost

I have been attempting to create a simple `TabActivity` with 3 Tabs.  All works *except* if I put `android:minSdkVersion="11"` in the Manifest file, the icons are not shown. If I set `minSdkVersion="10", all is well.

I have looked high and low, but I have not been able to determine what is wrong.
I have put the same images in the seemingly appropriate resource directories:

> res/drawable-hdpi-v5
>   res/drawable-ldpi-v5
>   res/drawable-mdpi-v5
>   res/drawable-xhdpi-v5

And the the code is simple:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;

public class Review extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TabHost tabs = getTabHost();
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, 
                                    tabs.getTabContentView(), true);
        Resources resources=getResources();
        Log.d("testing", String.format("icon: %d.%d",
                    resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.review).getIntrinsicWidth(), 
            resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.review).getIntrinsicHeight()));
        TabHost.TabSpec details = tabs.newTabSpec("review"). setContent(R.id.review). 
                setIndicator(getString(R.string.review), 
                        resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.review));        
        TabHost.TabSpec gallery=tabs.newTabSpec("gallery").setContent(R.id.photos)
                .setIndicator(getString(R.string.gallery), 
                        resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.photos));
        TabHost.TabSpec reservation=tabs.newTabSpec("reservation").
             setContent(R.id.reservation)
                .setIndicator(getString(R.string.reservation), 
                        resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.reservation));
        tabs.addTab(details);
        tabs.addTab(gallery);
        tabs.addTab(reservation);    
    }
}
```

In digging into this, the only difference I can see internally under android 2.0 vs 3.0 is that Android uses a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` in the 2.0 implementation.

Just to be certain that the icons images are being found, `Log.d` of above shows:

> *icon: 32.32* as it should.

Why does this shift from android 2.0 to 3.0 do this???? I am hopeful that someone else has run into this and it is obvious.  Thanks very much for your help!

-- UPDATE:

I discovered today, as I looked more closely at what is actually happening when this code is built for android 3.0+, I learned that the `ImageView`'s that come about when `SetIndeicator(string, drawable)` is called for each `TabSpec`, are actually never set and are actually `NULL` (`ImageView.mDrawable==null`) and `INVISBLE`.

If I force set those drawables to be set, *and* call `ImageView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)` then they show up.  However under android 2.0 they appear stacked with the image above and the text below as in:

`<image>`
`<text>`

Under android 3.0 they appear (when forced as above) side by side as in:

`<image><text>`

Thus it seems that things have changed a great deal and I need to investigate the changes for android 3.0 more carefully.

Stay tuned for more...

-- Final UPDATE:

Ultimately, I abandoned this avenue and decided that this style of doing things changed and is perhaps now depreciated and there are other better ways to do this and the icons are a bit old style.

Answer (score 0):

strange, this solves the problem

> ```
>     //bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
>     //or better
>     bmOptions.inScaled = false;
> ```

more at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12088287/1320686