# Android : Load image from web URL

Tags: android, url, imageview, android-imageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading remote images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075637/loading-remote-images)

I am developing an application where I have a list in which each row has an image,

this image is loaded from a web URL.

below is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_row_img"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_row_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the activity code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.list_row_img);
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
         URL aURL = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
         URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
         conn.connect();
         InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
         bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
         img.setImageBitmap(bm);
         bis.close();
         is.close();

         } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("EXCEPTION", "Error getting bitmap", e);
         }
}
```

when I run i get nothing on the device. only a gray screen and no exception happens.

note that i added this permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code for download image from url and display image into imageview, this will solve your problem.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView mImgView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        mImgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgView1);
        String url = "https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Trial_Sizes_4e4ac3b0d3491_175x175.jpg";
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bm = loadBitmap(url, bmOptions);
        mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help . i have a question please.

OpenHttpConnection(URL) this line has an error

is there an API or library I need to import ?

Comment: @RanaOsama no, there is no need to any api or library.

Comment: @RanaOsama Please see my updated answer for import packages.

Comment: I get the following error

The method OpenHttpConnection(String) is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: @RanaOsama First clean your project and then run it again.

Comment: Although this worked, I advised you to use AsyncTask when downloading from the server. Bypassing the StrictMode.ThreadPolicy is not a good idea.

Comment: @Lazy I used async task when loading the image in this code.

I used your code with Dipak's and it worked with me

Thank you again =)

Comment: Did not work for me. "Unfortunately the app closed"

Answer (score 10):

try this
you can exeecute it by

```
      new DownloadImageTask((ImageView)  im1).execute(url here);
```

---

```
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }


/*    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgressDialog();
    }*/

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //pDlg.dismiss();
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }}
```

Comment: @Rana Osama  tried this code???

Comment: not yet but will work on it now ... thank you very much for your help =)

Comment: Short but beautiful answer. Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The link for your image is invalid. Try to access it with your browser, you will find out. thats your problem.

Comment: +1 for actually checking the link

Comment: @ Gautam K @Lazy Ninja the link is valid loads an image "although its tagged no image its an image"

Comment: the link is working. have u faced any problems with it ? @Lazy ?

Comment: Yes there is a problem. Change the url with this and check http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Galunggung.jpg

Comment: ur link didn't work too. 

the URL is not the problem i am sure.

it's something wrong when loading the image or getting the content of the URL