# Theme.Holo doesn't show Tabhost Widget icons

Tags: android, android-tabhost, uitabbar, tabwidget, android-theme

I'm using Theme.Holo as my parent theme for an application. However, the tabs in the tab host don't display icons. In order to display icons, I can change the theme to Theme.Light or just Theme, but then I won't have the action bar that comes with Theme.Holo.

Could someone please tell me how I could display icons on the tab host when using Theme.Holo? I'm referring to the iOS-like tab bar icons.

Comment: Can you provide code of creating tab indicators? What sdk are you targeting?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379916/adding-an-action-bar-to-theme-black-notitlebar-android check this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like iconed tabs are not used anymore.

You can use a great library I use for tabs ([ViewPagerExtentions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions)) which lets you swipe between tabs, and to set icon for every tab, like below:
[image]

You need to download the library. In the example project the layout you want is: `activity_fixed_icon_tabs.xml`.
It is quite straight forward but if you need any help you can ask me.

If you don't want to get your hands dirty, there is a solution for your problem, provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747507/why-are-the-images-in-widgettab-not-shown-if-minsdkversion10).
Basically you can get to the ImageView inside the tab and call `img.setVisibillity(View.VISIBLE)`.

Then he says that in android<3.0 it messes up the tab, but he provides a solution for this also. You can check which android version the device runs, and then do accordingly.
But as I understand, it won't be a problem for you because you want to use the `ActionBar` always.

I recommend you to use the [ViewPagerExtentions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) library because it also adds swipe functionallity which is very fancy. But even if you don't want to use this, you have a solution.

Comment: Interesting. However, I'd much appreciate a way to do this using the built-in tab host... A +1, and I'll give you the bounty if no other answers appear.

Comment: Great libraries are always welcome. @RichardJ.RossIII I have an app which utilizes the TabHost and working on all versions AFAIK. If no one answers I will prepare a small tutorial.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I did give you a solution to use with the `TabHost`.
Here the post again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747507/why-are-the-images-in-widgettab-not-shown-if-minsdkversion10

Look at the update in the end of his message

Answer (score 3):

Dont know if this solves your problem, but if you remove the text, the icon will be displayed.

This is the code I use:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Overview.class);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("overview")
           .setIndicator(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11 ? this.getString(R.string.descr) : "", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_overview))
           .setContent(intent);
```